# How to find the integral of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to calculuate:

$$\oint_C 2xy + 3x^2 + 4y^2 ds$$

where $C$ is the ellipse with the equation $\frac{x^2}4 + \frac{y^2}3 = 1.$

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Do you know how to take a contour integral?